# Get length of opposite from adjacent and angle

Tags: math, trigonometry

Im trying to determine where a "shot" will hit the wall from a position and an angle.
The player shoots a ball from a certain point with a certain angle towards a wall. And I want to be able to determine if the ball will hit within the bounds of the goal.

This is what i know:

origin: the ball's coordinates

length: the distance to the wall

angle: the angle of the shot

This is what i want to calculate:

point: the position the ball will have when it hits the wall

[image: where is point?]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should go here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does the ball have velocity?  Or does it just continue until it hits the wall and then stops?

Comment: If not v then a.  Are we to assume that this is happening under Earth g (9.8m or 32 ft)sec^2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unless i'm missing something:

```
point y = origin y + length
point x = origin x - length * tan(angle)
```

Comment: I think that looks similar to what I was going to suggest, but basically as Chris's answer pointed out, the main thing is tangent in this case.

Comment: I know, I was just commenting that the primary take away from your answer is the tangent (which you have).

Comment: Hmm i got a weird result with "origin x - length", but when I tried "origin x + length" i got better results. Not quite there yet though.

Are you sure that it should be - ?

Comment: @oskob: that would depend on how you are measuring your angles. If x increases to the right and your angle is measured clockwise from the vertical then adding would be correct (the angle you have shown would be negative in this case).

Comment: @oskob: I am using the orientation based on the diagram, where x corresponds to left-right and y corresponds to top-bottom.  From how its drawn, moving left decreases x.

Comment: Oh I messed up my angle calculation, it now works like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in Trig for a right angled triangle Tan(angle) = opposite/adjacent.

This should be all you need to get your position.

It should be noted that this is not a programming question as such and there are probably other places for Maths questions like this. :)

Comment: It would be quite interesting who downvoted these answers and for what reason.

Comment: @Christian Rau: Yes... That is a bit strange... I wish there was some way to report a downvoting. Maybe somebody objected to me answering a question whcih didn't really involve coding...

Comment: Guess the downvoter might be programmer who thinks that this is programming question too.

The programming world is now getting new set of programmers who primarily program in mobile/portable devices. 

On the mobile the screen sizes are mostly specified in inches diagnally 5.3,5,4.7 etc however they sport displays which are in 16:9,16:10,4:3..etc ratios. when an app needs extensive support for most devices programmers have to do calculations for possible adjacent and opposites to display content appropriately sized. 

tan(90) is undefined and thus Tan(angle) = opposite/adjacent might not suit

Comment: @RamaKrishnaChunduri: This is a somewhat zombied question but to address your point this question isn't about mobile screen sizes and in this case you might need to check the angle is within certain bounds first. 90 degrees or greater will clearly never hit the wall so no need to even do the calculation here. For working out true dimensions based on diagonal and aspect ratio I wouldn't be using trig functions anyway, just pythagoras's theorem and similar triangles.

Comment: @chris : Agreed ... Thanks for explanation. I like the idea of using pythagoras theorem that helped me lot...